# Type 'x' is not assignable to type never error after I return from a function

Tags: typescript, web, types, tsx

I am new to typescript and I already hate it, I use React js and I tried to do something super simple, here is the code:

```
 const nav = useRef(null);

  function toggleNavbar() {
    const navbar: object | null = nav.current;
    if (!navbar) return;

    navbar["style"]["transform"] = "translate(0)";
  }
```

I get the error type string is not assignable to type never after I conditionally return.
`navbar["style"]["transform"] = "translate(0)";` here the navbar is of type never. How to fix that? I already defined a type for it

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/typescript-react-useref/ The type you've used (object) is extremely narrow. You should try to type it using the type arg to useRef and using as accurate of a type as possible. `HTMLElement` is a reasonable choice if you truly don't know what DOM element it will be (or don't want to bind yourself too specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Don't use `object`

`object` is a *super vague* type.

`object['style']` can be anything, including `null`, `undefined`, etc.

The TypeScript compiler can't know that `object['style']` is something that can have a `transform` property.

Don't use `object`. Use the **actual** type.

## Define the type when you create the reference

Don't define the type here: `const navbar: object | null = nav.current;`

Define it here:

```
const nav = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
```

## BUT!!! Don't use references when you don't have to.

Direct DOM access is sometimes useful in React, but is usually more trouble than it is worth. React is *designed* to manage your DOM for you.

Focus on your data instead.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
     const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

     return (<div>
         <button type="button" onClick={() => setIsOpen(prev => !prev)}>
             Toggle
         </button>
         <nav style={{ transform: isOpen ? "translate(0)" : "" }}>...</nav>
     </div>);
}
```